# Error: raise ValueError("No element found in %s" % response) occur when try to login with scrappy

Tags: python, scrapy

## **Problem Description:**

I want to crawl some info from the bbs of my college. Here is the address:http://bbs.byr.cn
Below is the code of my spider:

```
from lxml import etree
import scrapy
try:
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
except:
from scrapy.spiders import BaseSpider as Spider
from scrapy.http import Request

class ITJobInfoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "ITJobInfoSpider"
start_urls = ["http://bbs.byr.cn/#!login"]

def parse(self,response):
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={'method':'post','id': 'username', 'passwd':'password'},
        formxpath='//form[@action="/login"]',
        callback=self.after_login
)

def after_login(self,response):
    print "######response body: " + response.body +"\n"
    if "authentication failed" in response.body:
        print "#######Login failed#########\n"
    return
```

However, with this code, I often get an Error: raise ValueError("No element found in %s" % response)

## **My Investigation:**

I find that this Error happens when scrapy try to parse the HTML code of the url: http://bbs.byr.cn, scrappy parses the page with lxml. Below is the code

```
root = LxmlDocument(response, lxml.html.HTMLParser)
forms = root.xpath('//form')
if not forms:
    raise ValueError("No <form> element found in %s" % response)
```

So I look into the code with the code:
    `print etree.tostring(root)`
And find that HTML element:`</form>`is parsed into `&lt;/form&gt;`
no wonder the code `forms = root.xpath('//form')` will return an empty forms list.

> But I don't know why this is happening, maybe the HTML code encoding? (The HTML code is encoded with GBK not UTF8.) 
>   Thanks advance for anyone who can help me out? BTW, if anyone want to write code against the website, I can give you an test account, pls leave me an email address in the comment.

Thanks a lot, guys!!

Comment: etree.tostring(root),("No element found in %s" % response), dont convert to string use default module parser.Check:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html And check forms is not empty !

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do you mean I should get root element with the code below:`root = LxmlDocument(response)`? This won't work.

Comment: give me test user acoount and pass (id=test,password=test)

Comment: I may just solve my problem, but don't know the reason. I send request to [link]http://bbs.byr.cn/index, then I can login successfully. But send request to [link]http://bbs.byr.cn/ won't work. Also, I notice that when I send request to [link]http://bbs.byr.cn/, the HTML code in the response is the same with the web page, however, the HTML code I saw after the parse is different.

Comment: @SDilmac It's hanx415/hanx415

Comment: I think may be the redirection is the reason. When send request to [link]http://bbs.byr.cn, the request will be redirected to [link]http://bbs.byr.cn/index. Maybe that's the reason why I fail. Because the request URL is wrong. However, I use the code `etree.tostring(root,encoding='utf8')`, this time, everything else displays fine, except <form> element. It still displays as the symptom above. May you know the reason? @SDilmac

Comment: lxml.html.HTMLParser = escape html char. corrupted form

Comment: @SDilmac Do you mean `lxml.html.HTMLParser.unescape(escape_string)`?

Comment: I haven't found any escape method, only an unescape method.

Comment: HTML if you add "utf-8" in his head, there's no need to parse again.
I already have the "POST" method.
In addition, elementree does not support non-unique values.
Values from continuous print, you must decide what to do in case of an occurrence of an error.

Comment: Sorry, @SDilmac,I'm new to python and scrapy. I don't understand what are you saying int the last comment. I asked that did you know the reason why  I get `&lt;` instead of '<' in the response? May be I should escapes or unescape some characters? Or I should add an UTF8 header in the HTML code? BTW, thanks a lot for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some JavaScript redirection happening.

In this case using [Splash](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) would be overkill, though. Simply append `/index` to the start URL: `http://bbs.byr.cn → http://bbs.byr.cn/index`

This would be the complete working spider:

```py
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import FormRequest

class ByrSpider(Spider):
    name = 'byr'
    start_urls = ['http://bbs.byr.cn/index']

    def parse(self, response):
        return FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'method':'post','id': 'username', 'passwd':'password'},
            formxpath='//form[@action="/login"]',
            callback=self.after_login)

    def after_login(self, response):
        self.logger.debug(response.text)
        if 'authentication failed' in response.text:
            self.logger.debug('Login failed')
```